# Is there a way to prevent my IDE from changing owner/group of a file after deployment?

Tags: linux, deployment, ftp

The group of files deployed via NetBeans is always changed from `www` to `ftp-users` and thus the webserver looses the rights to access the file and nothing works anymore.

Before modifiying a file:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 black www   5 May  3 14:11 kontakt_formular.html
```

After modifiying a file:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 black ftp-users 5 May  3 14:11 kontakt_formular.html
```

Is there a way to keep the group of a file?

I always have to connect to the server via putty and use `chown` to fix it after making a change to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files created through ftp will always be assigned to the user you use to login to the ftp server.
You can add the www user to the ftp-users group and fix the permissions for group. That will allow your webserver to access the files.

**Edit by Black:**

1. Figure out the name of the webserver user.
   Open the file `/etc/passwd` and search for it. It is usually `wwwrun`.
2. Open the file `/etc/groups` and add the webserver user (`wwwrun`) to the group `ftp-users`.
3. Restart the webserver. (e.g. `systemctl restart apache2`)

Comment: But www is not a user, it is a group. I can't add a group to a group

Comment: The Apache server runs with a user that is usually the same as the group.

Anyway, there is another way, you can force a folder to have all it's future files and folders inherit it's permissions, follow the accepted answer from here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux

Comment: I added `www` to `ftp-users` in `/etc/group` but the problems persist, the webserver can't write to the file. This is the entry: `ftp-users:x:1000:www
`

Comment: I figured out that there is a user called `wwwrun` in `/etc/passwd` where all users are stored. So I added this user instead of `www` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It works now. I just had to restart the webserver after adding the user `wwwrun` to the group `ftp-users` :) Thx for your help!

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but you should remove the 'netbeans' tags since it has nothing to do with the editor you are using, it's more related to user permissions.

Comment: Another thing, to be easier to find by other people, maybe the title should be something like: "Apache can't access files created by ftp"